# pyspark - how to handle unicode from hive

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, python-unicode

I am trying read a hive table in pyspark

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext 
from pyspark import HiveContext 
hivec = HiveContext(sc) sqlc = SQLContext(sc) 
t = hivec.sql("select * from database.table").collect()

data = sqlc.createDataFrame(t)
data.registerTempTable("masterTable")
sqlc.sql("select * from masterTable").show()
```

I get the below error

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ufffd' in
>   position 8871: ordinal not in range(128)

What I have tried:

I figured out the record that was falling over, when I "select * from    " in hive for the same record, there is no error reported nor can I    see any unicode
 - `t = hivec.sql("select * from database.table").collect()` there are    no errors reported in t variable itself

```
   '>>>t
   prints out all the rows
```

As soon as t  gets converted to DataFrame the issue pops up

I tried encoding and decoding, combination between 'utf-8' and    'ascii' mainly as I couldn't tell if the field was a unicode or a ascii visually as hive select nor printing the list was showing anything visible or throwing errors.

```
data.select(*(c.encode("ascii","ignore") if not isinstance(c,unicode) else c for c in data.columns )).show(10)
```

Throws the same error. Any suggestions how to get around this?

Comment: `s = u'\ufffd'; print s.encode('utf8')` shows �. Did you use 'utf-8' instead of 'utf8' ?

Comment: s = u'\ufffd'; print s.encode('utf-8') also shows �. The issue is  with DataFrames under pyspark I think